# Home/End keys to simulate Windows behavior in different contexts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Going to Mac from Windows is mostly a nice experience for me, but one thing I struggle with massively is keyboard shortcuts. I am a programmer and I use them a lot. I have mapped most of them to my liking using Karabiner, but I can't seem to figure out how to simulate Home/End behavior.

The basic behavior, going to the beginning/end of a line is easy, I just mapped Home/End to Command+Left/Right.

However, the issue is with non-text fields. For example, if I am on a webpage and I don't have a text field focused (just clicked anywhere on the page), I would expect the Home/End keys to scroll all the way to the top/bottom of the page. The problem is that pressing those keys effectively means pressing Cmd+Left/Right and that (in the context of a browser) means "go to the previous/next page". So I need to press Cmd+Up/Down to go up and down the page.

But I want to basically have Home behave as "go to the start/top of the current element, whatever that means - if text field, to the beginning. If long page, dialog, something - to the top". Just like on Windows. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) software.  It allows you to "program" key functionality based on context.  For example, I have a second keyboard attached to my Mac and the `Q` key assigned to some mark down code in web browsers and assigned to a ratings value in Lightroom.  It works great.  It's priced at $25USD and I found it quite reasonable for it's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Google Chrome, you can add an Extension called Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts) and set all the custom shortcuts you want.

PS: Just FYI you can press `Space` to go down one screen at a time and `Shift+Space` to go up from default.

[image]

[image]