# Override the command+tab shortcut in macOS Catalina when using Chrome

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

Most Chrome shortcuts I use, use the command key: command+T, command+W, etc. However, the shortcut for switching tabs is control+tab (and control+shift+tab). I'd like to have all Chrome shortcuts use command.

There are 2 issues:

1. How do I disable macOS's native behavior, which is to switch apps using command+tab (and command+shift+tab)?
2. How do I get chrome to switch tabs using command+tab (and command+shift+tab), instead of control?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant use `control + tab` and `control + shift + tab` instead?

Comment: I want to use the same key for all shortcuts in Chrome: commant+T, command+W, command+tab, etc. I don't mind having using control for everything instead (because I can flip control and command in macOS), the important thing is to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple: "[...] you cannot define keyboard shortcuts for general purpose tasks such as opening an app **or switching between apps**."

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-global-keyboard-shortcuts-mchlp2262/mac

However you can use custom Chrome shortcuts using an extension:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341531/197509

I wouldn't bother tho. This behaviour is consistent if you think that Finder uses the same keys regarding tabs, and pretty much any app will follow the same pattern. Getting used with a different scheme will annoy you whenever you sit on another computer. It is way more efficient to just teach your brain to adapt.